# Using dplyr to conditionally update multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use a single conditional statement to update multiple variables in R using dplyr.  I have some working code (posted below) however I feel it is very inefficient and am convinced there must be a better way of doing it.

EDIT:  Worded description of purpose of the program. The idea is to take the iris dataset an update multiple variables based upon the value of Species, for example if Species == "setosa"  then Species = "SETOSA" , Sepal.Length *= 1.5 , Sepal.Width *= 0.5.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

multi_update <- function(species , sepal.length , sepal.width , ret){

  if ( species == "setosa")  {
    RET <- list( 
      Species      = "SETOSA",
      Sepal.Length = sepal.length * 1.5,
      Sepal.Width  = sepal.width * 0.5
    )
  } else if ( species == "versicolor") {
    RET <- list( 
      Species      = "VERSI",
      Sepal.Length = sepal.length * 2,
      Sepal.Width  = sepal.width * 1.5
    )
  } else {
    RET <- list( 
      Species      = species,
      Sepal.Length = sepal.length ,
      Sepal.Width  = sepal.width 
    )
  }                     
  return( RET[[ret]] )
}

iris %>% 
  tbl_df %>% 
  mutate( Sepal.Length = mapply(multi_update , Species , Sepal.Length , Sepal.Width , "Sepal.Length")) %>% 
  mutate( Sepal.Width  = mapply(multi_update , Species , Sepal.Length , Sepal.Width , "Sepal.Width")) %>% 
  mutate( Species      = mapply(multi_update , Species , Sepal.Length , Sepal.Width , "Species"))
```

Comment: I think it is better to create a key/variable dataset and then join with the original dataset

Comment: Please include a description (in words) of what your function is supposed to do so others don't have to guess its purpose

Comment: `iris %>% mutate(sp = if_else(Species %in% c("setosa", "versicolor"), Species, NA_integer_),
                Sepal.Length = if_else(Species == "setosa", Sepal.Length * 1.5, Sepal.Length * 2, Sepal.Length))`

Comment: Updated to include a worded description as requested by @docendodiscimus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a key val dataset, `join` with the original dataset and `mutate` the columns

```
library(dplyr)
kval <- data.frame(Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
       Species.x = c("SETOSA", "VERSI", "virginica"), 
      Sepal.Length = c(1.5, 2, 1), Sepal.Width = c(0.5, 1.5, 1))
res <- left_join(iris, kval, by = "Species") %>% 
           mutate(Species = Species.x, Sepal.Length = Sepal.Length.x*Sepal.Length.y, 
             Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width.x * Sepal.Width.y) %>%
            select(-matches("(.x|.y)$"))
head(res)
#  Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#1          1.4         0.2  SETOSA         7.65        1.75
#2          1.4         0.2  SETOSA         7.35        1.50
#3          1.3         0.2  SETOSA         7.05        1.60
#4          1.5         0.2  SETOSA         6.90        1.55
#5          1.4         0.2  SETOSA         7.50        1.80
#6          1.7         0.4  SETOSA         8.10        1.95
```

Comment: This works well,  how would you expand it though for more complex derivations for example 

    if  setosa   then    Sepal.Length =  Sepal.Length * 1.5
    if  viginica  then   Sepal.Length = 12 
    if   ....         then  Sepal.Length = Sepal.Lenth - 2

Comment: @C_G You can update the keyval dataset `kval` based on what ever new values you have, So, in the new case, change the 'Species' to that corresponding with the value from Sepal.Length.  The advantage of this method is that you can have 100s of key/val pairs and do a singe join instead of many nested ifelse

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Sorry If I am being dim but I don't quite get you you would modify your example for various operators, your example seems to be fixed on multiplication, what if I wanted multiplication for some and addition or subtraction for others ?

Comment: @C_G Whatever you wanted, you can add additional columns in the key val dataset and then join by the common Species, so it will be easier for you to multiply or add various columns on the same row.

Comment: @C_G For example if you want the Petal.Length as well `mutate(Species = Species.x, NewLength = Sepal.Length.x*Sepal.Length.y + Petal.Length)`

Comment: O sorry I see I more meant :

If Species = "setosa" then Sepal.length = Sepal.length * 10.  If species = "veri..." then Sepal.length = Sepal.Length + 10.   

I.e. the actual function  varies based upon the species not just the values in the function if that makes sense.

Comment: @C_G In that case, change it in the `kval <- data.frame(Species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
       Species.x = c("SETOSA", "VERSI", "virginica"), 
      Sepal.Length = c(10, 10, 1), Sepal.Width = c(0.5, 1.5, 1), Fun1 = c("*", "+", "+"))` and then do the processing based on it.  I think this should be a new question as your posted question is already answered