# assign multiple values with conditional mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

Can a single conditional mutate call be used to assign values to multiple variables?

For example, in the example below, when `cat == "a"`, I want to assign the value "1" to a column "foo", as well as the value "three" to a column "bar". Likewise when `cat == "b"`, assign "2" and "four".

The following achieves this, but requires that the call to `case_when` be repeated for each variable

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(cat = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c"))
df %>%
  mutate(foo = case_when(cat == "a" ~ 1,
                         cat == "b" ~ 2,
                         TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>%
  mutate(bar = case_when(cat == "a" ~ "three",
                         cat == "b" ~ "four",
                         TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

I thought that creating a list column might be useful, something along the lines of

```
df %>%
  mutate(case_when(cat == "a" ~ list("foo" = 1, "bar" = "three"),
                   cat == "b" ~ list("foo" = 2, "bar" = "four"),
                   TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

but `case_when` only accepts single values for the RHS.

One solution (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117349/using-dplyr-to-conditionally-update-multiple-variables)) is to create a 'reference' dataframe, and `join` it, for example

```
require(tidyverse)    
ref <- tibble(cat = c("a", "b"), foo = c(1, 2), bar = c("three", "four"))
df %>% left_join(ref)
```

however this won't work when the 'condition' is not categorical, e.g. `x > 2`

Any suggestions for a nice way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the `join` method but with an intermediate column:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(cat = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L))
otherdf <- data_frame(j=c('a1','a2','a99'), foo=11:13, bar=c('three','four','five'))

df %>%
  mutate(
    j = case_when(
      cat == 1L ~ 'a1',
      cat == 2L ~ 'a2',
      cat > 2L ~ 'a99'
    )) %>%
  left_join(otherdf, by = 'j')
# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#     cat     j   foo   bar
#   <int> <chr> <int> <chr>
# 1     1    a1    11 three
# 2     2    a2    12  four
# 3     3   a99    13  five
# 4     4   a99    13  five
```

(Then you can obviously clean it up with `select(-j)`.)

Comment: Thanks very much @r2evans (and other posters below). Your work-around works as desired, and is flexible. Though in the future it would be nice to see this functionality in `case_when` (or similar)

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is quite close to `data.table` functionality, where you can supply a list of columns and values to be updated (by reference, i.e. without copy) based on a certain condition:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df) # or use setDT(df)
dt[cat == "a", `:=`(foo = 1, bar = "three")]
dt[cat == "b", `:=`(foo = 2, bar = "four")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how scalable the whole thing should be. Might be worth a look:

```
require(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(cat = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c"))

# create single case_when
make_fun <- function(values) {
  trans_fun <- function(x) {
    case_when(x == "a" ~ values[[1]],
              x == "b" ~ values[[2]],
              TRUE ~ values[[3]])
  }
}

# create all case_whens
fun_list <- list(
  foo = make_fun(list(1, 2, NA_real_)),
  bar = make_fun(list("three", "four", NA_character_)))

# join is not really necessary
df %>%
  bind_cols(map(fun_list, 
                function(f) f(df %>%
                                select(cat))))
```